# how do you obtain the address of an instance after overriding the __str__ method in python

Tags: python, string, memory-address

```
class Bar:
     pass

class Foo:
     def __str__(self): return "Foo instance"

>> aBar = Bar()
>> print aBar
<__main__.Bar instance at 0x100572a28>
>> aFoo = Foo()
>> print aFoo
Foo instance
```

is there a way to print out the address of aFoo after overriding the **str** method?

using

```
 >>repr(aFoo)
```

solved my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least in cpython, `id` provides the address. But the output is in decimal; you have to convert that to hex:

```
>>> f = (x for x in [1,2,3])
>>> print f
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1004d22d0>
>>> '%x' % id(f)
'1004d22d0'
```

---

Actually, though, the `__repr__` function isn't altered when `__str__` is overridden. So you can do this as well:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __str__(self): return "Foo instance"
... 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> print a
Foo instance
>>> print repr(a)
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x1004d1c68>
```

I think `id` is preferable for this, if what you want is really the `id`. But `id` is not guaranteed to return the address; that's just the cpython implementation. I don't know whether it's specified that the built-in `__repr__` of objects has to return an address, or whether it has to return the `id`, or neither. So if you specifically want whatever it is that `__repr__` provides, then this may be the way to go.

**Update**: The answer is neither, at least according to the [language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), which dictates only that the `__repr__` of an object be "information-rich and unambiguous." And indeed, sometimes the `__repr__` does not actually return the address of the specific object in question, as seen here:

```
>>> a = Foo()
>>> '%x' % id(a)
'1004d1fc8'
>>> '%x' % id(a.__str__)
'1004745a0'
>>> '%x' % id(Foo.__str__)
'1004745a0'
>>> repr(a.__str__)
'<bound method Foo.__str__ of <__main__.Foo instance at 0x1004d1fc8>>'
```

Comment: On .Net objects don't have a fixed address so there's no way that the IronPython repr can include an address: .Net garbage collection moves objects around so that free memory is nearly contiguous. I'm not sure about Jython but it may well be the same.

Comment: @Duncan, I thought as much. Not having an IronPython installation to test, what does IronPython provide in default `__repr__` methods? Is it the same as the value returned by `id`?

Comment: yes it is the value returned by `id()` but the id isn't assigned until `id()` is called and is a simple increasing count. For example I just created 4 instances (a,b, c, d) of a class then printed their `repr()` in arbitrary order (d, b, c, a) and the ids match the order in which I printed them: `id(a), id(b), id(c), id(d)` gives `(48, 46, 47, 45)`.

Comment: @Duncan, thanks -- good to know. I guess lazy assignment of ids is an optimal approach in that case, although I think it gently stretches the definition of `id` as providing an id number that is "unique and constant for this object during its lifetime."