# How to create an object of an instance from string in Python

Tags: python, eval, maya, repr

I'm working in Maya using Python 2.5, writing a dynamic hotkey manager class and ran into trouble trying to assign commands that are instance specific since nameCommands get represented as strings in mel. I end up with commands that look like:

```
<bla.Bla instance at 0x0000000028F04388>.thing = 'Dude'
```

I've seen quite a bit on the topic of repr and eval but my test example below fails.

```
class Foo:
    pass

f = Foo()
f.thing = 'Jeff'
rep = repr(f)
y = eval(rep) # errors here
name = y.thing

# Error: invalid syntax
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 7, in <module>
#   File "<string>", line 1
#     <__main__.Foo instance at 0x00000000294D8188>
#     ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax #
```

I assume what I want is some way to get a proper object of that instance from a string.
I could format the string to an evaluate-able command if I knew what that looked like.
[see my cgtalk post for more usage info](http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?f=89&t=1158276)

SO related topics:

This one says it's not possible but users also wanted a use case, which I hope I've provided.
[How to obtain an object from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968560/how-to-obtain-an-object-from-a-string)

Others:
[When is the output of repr useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661851/when-is-the-output-of-repr-useful/4661901#4661901)
[How to print a class or objects of class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/python-how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print)
[Allowing the repr() of my class's instances to be parsed by eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656645/allowing-the-repr-of-my-classs-instances-to-be-parsed-by-eval)
[Main purpose of __repr__ in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661063/main-purpose-of-repr-in-python/15661434#15661434)
[how do you obtain the address of an instance after overriding the __str__ method in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219446/how-do-you-obtain-the-address-of-an-instance-after-overriding-the-str-method/6219468#6219468)
[Python repr for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362183/python-repr-for-classes)
[how to use 'pickle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019489/how-to-use-pickle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a method that seems to work for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702647/1495017) using the id as a string and ctypes

```
class Foo:
    pass

f = Foo()
f.thing = 'Jeff'

import ctypes    
long_f = id(f)
y = ctypes.cast(long_f,ctypes.py_object).value
name = y.thing
```

and here, an example usage in Maya;

```
command = ("python(\"ctypes.cast(%s,ctypes.py_object).value.thing=False\")")%(id(self))
nameCommand = cmds.nameCommand( 'setThingOnPress', annotation='', command=command )
cmds.hotkey( keyShortcut='b', name=nameCommand)
```

Answer (score 2):

For `eval` to work, the builtin `__repr__` function needs to be overriden. I don't see you mentioning that, so I figure you didn't do it. I'm pasting a code snippet I wrote a while back. Just for the sake of demonstration. In this example, eval works because `__repr__` was overriden:

```
class element :
    def __init__(self, a, m):
        self.name = a ;
        self.atomic_mass = m ;

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} has atomic mass {1}".format(self.name, self.atomic_mass)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "element(\"{0}\", \"{1}\")".format(self.name, self.atomic_mass)

H = element("Hydrogen", 1.00794)
print H
print repr(H)
print eval(repr(H))
```

More here : http://www.muqube.com/python/string-representation-of-python-objects/

Comment: it looks like this creates a *new* instance rather than calling a method of the *existing* instance

Comment: think I just found a way actually using id rather then the rep string.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15702647/1495017
will fully implement to see if I run into any gotcha's.

Comment: @PaulLohman, I was just testing the same thing. It works beautifully

Comment: woot, using it as so;
command = ("python(\"ctypes.cast(%s,ctypes.py_object).value.thing=False\")")%(id(self))
nameCommand = cmds.nameCommand( 'setThingOnPress', annotation='', command=command )

Comment: @PaulLohman, you should post it as a new answer, and accept it. That way future visitors can see and learn from it. Be sure to also include a link to that other valuable answer you'd found

Comment: Is this all intended to rewrite parameters inside the runTimeCommand? If you have the runtimeCommand's name you can just change the text with cmds.runTimeCommand(name, e=True, commmand='your text here')